# Is there a difference between a manual and an automatic grinder?

Tags: grinder

Is there any notifiable difference between coffee beans grinder by an automatic grinder or a manual grinder like a hand-crank?

I see many people to swear on their manual grinder (me too) but I'm curious if there may be some difference. In many coffee shops there is an automatic grinder which puts a kilogram of coffee through in a few seconds.

I have the temperature in mind. Maybe this change the taste of the coffee?

Comment: What do you mean by 'manual'? A hand-crank? Or are you asking about burrs v. blades, or doser v. doser-less? Doser-less with some kind of automatic timing control? A motor will definitely create heat, but its effect can be reduced with an offset drive. But all friction (like grinding) produces heat, so some amount is par for the course.

Comment: Yes I mean the hand-crank with manual. Well yes there is heat but I think it may differ if I use a hand-crank I'm not quite as fast as if I'm using a automatic grinder which may produce a more aggressive heat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would anyone want to hand grind their coffee?](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/why-would-anyone-want-to-hand-grind-their-coffee)

Answer (score 4):

The most important differences I think, are ***time*** and ***temperature***.

I really don't know much technical details about grinders, but as @luser-droog said, friction will create heat and ***it will*** affect the coffee (so, motor grinders can be affected by this if doesn't manage heat dissipation well)

And of course, in all cases, ***time matters***; so, time might be a crucial factor for someone.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most important part of your question is about the **quality** of the grinder in question. You have cheaper manual grinder, middle grade grinder (e.g. [Hario grinders](http://www.hario.jp/product/list.php?middelclass=1)) and high end grinder (e.g. [HG One](http://hg-one.com/) or [OE Pharos](http://www.oehandgrinders.com/OE-Manual-Coffee-Grinders_c_1.html)). The same goes for automatic one where you have cheap bladed grinders all the way up to Mazzers.

Higher end grinders (both manual and automatic) won't have notable difference in grind quality (e.g. the HG One has the same grinding burrs as the Mazzer). Both type will allow to pull great shots. The most notable difference will be in grinding speed, counter space used, price paid and your coffee making enjoyment.